# how to run Calabash on Xamarin with --tag option

Tags: xamarin, calabash, xamarin-test-cloud

I want to submit the calabash to xamarin test-cloud with the tags I want to run. When I add the `--tag` option it gives the following error:

```
test-cloud submit prebuilt/Moda.com.apk  93dwwwe5e0e1ec3b0d65099640f23 --devices 0c4wweaf --series "master" --locale "en_US" --app-name "Moda" --user gunesmes@gmail.com --config /Users/mesutgunes/Projects/moda/mobile_app_automation/config/cucumber.yml --tag "@header"
ERROR: "test-cloud submit" was called with arguments ["prebuilt/Moda.com.apk", "93dwwwe5e0e1ec3b0d65099640f23", "--tag", "@header"]
Usage: "test-cloud submit <APP> <API_KEY> -d, --devices=DEVICES"
```

what is the correct way of running with tags?

Comment: Doesn't look like the test-cloud command line too supports this.

Comment: @Cheesebaron is there a way to manage running scenarios? The provided command runs the whole set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are already using a cucumber.yml. That's great!

To specify which tags you want to use, add those tags to a profile in your cucumber.yml file. You can then specify which profile to run in Test Cloud with the parameter `--profile`

Here's a link with a bit [more info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/working-with/submitting-tests-to-xamarin-test-cloud/#Submitting_Calabash_Tests_).

Comment: Thanks it works by adding `--tag @regression` to config file